# iOS Show UIViewController as Popup from Anywhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios11

Basic question:

Is there a reliably way to trigger showing modal `UIViewControllers` at any point in the app's lifetime (including from different threads)?

My current approach is to call `presentViewController` on the showing ViewController (found through `window.rootViewController` + hierarchy traversing but that's unimportant). This generally works, but is sometimes ignored due to things like a navigation action/animation taking place.

E.g. a background thread signals for a popup to be shown, and `presentViewController` is called on a `ViewController` in the process of being dismissed.

I've tried a few work arounds such as repeating the signal if the `ViewController` isn't shown (which led to some instances of it being show multiple times), but it's ended up being a game of whackamole.

An ideal solution would also allow navigation to take place underneath the popup, but the primary issue right now is just reliability.

**edit**

To be clear, I’m a seasoned developer. The threading is being handled properly, the instance and type management is working. My problem is trying to manage all
the corner cases, not the basics of how to do it.

Comment: First of all any UI changes need to be done on the UI thread, so different threads is not an option. Second I'm guessing you want to show this at any time regardless of anything happening so why don't you simply add it on the window on top of everything and manually handle showing/hiding?

Comment: The threading is being handled properly, that’s not the problem. I tried working directly with the window at one point and had issues  it’s other things overlaying it. Should maybe give it another try.

Comment: What you need is making the class a singleton. that way, only one instance of the view will be loaded. and the show/hide will not overlap each other.

Comment: and +1 on @Lefteris comment - UI related updates must be done on main thread.

Comment: @GeneCode. See edit. Unfortunately that’s not my problem (and already using a singleton).

Comment: You need to show us how u creating the class. and also how u are using it.maybe we can have some idea what is wrong.

Comment: Without seeing ur code it’s just a guessing game for everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you need mechanism for thread safe showing different VCs in multithread environment, you can make some object which is responsible for presenting/dismissing controllers. And make some queue on presenting/dismissing. So when your signal occurs, your operation on presenting will be next after dismissing current VC in queue